# How can I import images from iPad into Capture One?

Tags: import, ipad

I have imported my photos to an iPad using the camera connection kit. How can I import these photos from the iPad into a Capture One 7 catalog?

Comment: Why don't you just import them from the camera to the Capture One Catalog?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - because he hasn't. Is it so hard to understand that other people have other preferences for their workflows? Or consider him having a small SD card, e.g. 8GB, but lots of memory on the iPad (64GB). So, the iPad can be used as a storage when the card gets full. Or he may have edited the imported images on the iPad with the Photo app. Lots of reasons.

Comment: I understand that people have different workflows. I'm just trying to clarify the situation.

Comment: I'm using ipad in travels to preview and discard obviously bad photos. I had not any problem with Aperture and this travel workflow, but currently I'm swtiching to C1 (Aperture is dead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to copy them off your iPad and onto a computer. The iPad won't function as a "camera" for this purpose and it won't attach as an external drive. However, once copied off the iPad, you can just import the files into Capture One normally.

Caveat, I don't use Capture One, so I'm not thoroughly familiar with their import functions. I do know that Lightroom, in contrast, will show import options for attached iPhone and iPad devices, so if you're not see something like that in Capture One, then the method I described is how I would do it.

Comment: I discovered Image Capture app to copy photo onto my mac.